# JQuery UI tooltip is misplaced when containing image without specified dimensions

Tags: jquery, image, position

I am trying to display a tooltip that contains a full version of an image when the user mouse over a thumbnail. I want the tooltip to be shown over and to the left from the thumbnail. The image can be set dynamically by user so I don't know it's size. Here is a fiddle that demonstrates it:

http://jsfiddle.net/philipp_ko/8HvgM/2/

```
$(function () {
    $(document).tooltip({
        show: false,
        hide: false,
        position: {
            my: "right bottom",
            at: "left top"

        },
        content: function () {
            var contentStr = "<img src='" + this.src + "'>";
            return contentStr;
        }
    });
});
```

As you can see, there are two similar images, one is located at wikimedia and another one on the dropbox. For the wikimedia image the tooltip is displayed correctly over the thumbnail, while for the dropbox image not. For none of them the tooltip is dispayed correctly horizontally. If I then specify the hieght and the width of the image, the tooltip is displayed correctly vertically and not completely correctly horizontally (see bullet point 2 below).

As I can see, there are 2 problems here:

- First, some servers provide the image dimensions when sending the response, while the others don't. This dimensions are then used by JQuery to calculate tooltip position. Does anyone know if this is the case and if yes, what should be done on the server side? Or if there is a way to make JQuery use the actual image size.
- Second, even if the size is set, it looks like the width of the tooltip container is limited to 400px, so if the image is larger, it is just displayed outside the container. However, this width is used by JQuery to calculate the position of the tooltip when it is to the left of the parent. Does anyone know why there is such limitation and how can it be worked around?

Thank you!